# how to remove event listener, set in jQuery, using pure JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, addeventlistener, event-listener

I have a situation where a click eventlistener is being set on on a dynamic element using jQuery's .on:

```
$('body').on('click', '#email-me', function() {
    call my code....
});
```

and later on in the page, I have to remove this listener - but - and here's the catch - I DON'T have access to jQuery anymore (long story), which means pure js...

so, I can't use `unBind()`, and even if i name my anonymous function up there, it still won't remove the event listener.

How do I remove the bind, so this element isn't clickable anymore?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: you can't. It's stored internally within jquery. I'd be interested to hear the (long story). If the event is still triggerable, then jquery is still around in some form or fashion.

Comment: You'd need to store a reference to the callback you originally pass. Then you could call `document.body.removeEventListener('click', refToCallback);`

Comment: @Matt yeah, this is the leaking point in my answer ;)

Comment: @Matt that won't work either, as jQuery binds using it's own event handler that then calls your function.

Comment: you can use this.removeEventListener('click', arguments.callee);

Comment: If you bind 10 events to one element using jQuery, jquery binds one event to the element and then stores the 10 handlers to call when the event gets triggered.

Comment: @KevinB actually, it seems to only wrap for `one()` calls? https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/c869a1ef8a031342e817a2c063179a787ff57239/src/event.js#L820

Comment: @KevinB it looks like jQuery would just add each 10 individually to the root element, if you stored all 10 refs, you could remove as normal. Best to jsfiddle at this point

Comment: follow the code up the tree, starting with jQuery.event.add. First, it gets the elemData which is jQuery's internal cache for the element. Next, look at the while loop that loops over the passed in handlers, you'll notice this comment: `// Init the event handler queue if we're the first` it only uses `addEventListener` once, after which it skips that portion and just adds the handler to the array of handlers stored in the cache.

Comment: Proof in favor of @KevinB for those curious: http://jsfiddle.net/R53LZ/1/

Comment: You've managed to get yourself in a predicament, what you should be doing is solving the issue with not having jQuery available, instead of trying to figure out how to remove stuff added with jQuery without using jQuery.

Comment: jQuery doesn't just disappear. If you had access to it at an earlier time on the same page, you can have access to it later. If something is clobbering the `jQuery` or `$` function name, save a reference to it while you still have one, and use that reference later.

Comment: it will actually be more efficient if we can help you restore jQuery funcationlity again instead of work-around this issue.. but, as Kevin says and i support, it cannot be done in any other way except jQuery..

Comment: so, I don't have access to jQuery because i'm inside a callback function, that's part of external js file, that is added to the page, and is encapsulated. the original binding (the code above) is done on a dynamic element, that is dynamically created with jquery, and i really don't to go back and re-write a buncha code to create it in pure js. hope this makes sense. thanks for all the help, everyone - it sounds like this isn't do-able, i'll figure out some other solution...

Comment: I don't see anything in that explanationa that explains why you can't access `window.jQuery`

Comment: That, Kevin, is a A GREAT suggestion :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. jQuery events are handled differently than normal javascript events.

When you add an event to an element with jQuery, these steps are followed:

1. If the element hasn't been initialized with an internal (internal to jquery) datacache, it gets initialized with a datacache, then the datacache is returned.
2. If this is the first event handler added for that event type, a **special event** is added to the element for that event type that executes `jQuery.event.dispatch`.
3. Finally, the handler(s) that you passed in are added to the datacache.

Therefore, the only way for you to remove this event is to get ahold of the **special event** handler that jQuery bound that triggers `jQuery.event.dispatch`, but since you don't have access to jQuery, there's no way you will get that event handler. <strike>(even with access to jQuery, I don't think you can get that handler.)</strike>

You need to instead find a way to retain access to jQuery, or don't use it at all.